# What's difference between rand, urand and irand in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, random

What is the difference between these three functions ?

Comment: `urand()` and `irand()` are not part of the standard library.  What libraries are you taking them from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those aren't standard functions, but usually it's the return type: signed int, unsigned, and 32-bit respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Only `rand` function is defined by the C and C++ Standards.

`rand` returns a pseudo random integer of type `int` between 0 and `RAND_MAX`.
The choice of the algorithm is left to the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The return type is different. But only [`rand()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/) is standard C/C++ function.